# SID changes after reboot

Tags: reboot

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 WSL2. SID, which is tied to and acquired by a software, always changes when I reboot the PC. The effect of this is that I always have to renew a license of the software. Are there any way to change SID manually or not to change it when rebooting?

Comment: What's SID? Is it installed in the "guest" Ubuntu or the "host" Windows?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My understanding is that SID is a security ID in Windows. However, what is called sid in my case may not mean what it usually means since the SID acquired on Windows Command prompt and that on Ubuntu are different. I will ask the developers about it. The software is installed in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

SID stands for Security Identifier and is a Windows version of Linux `id $USER`. There is no mapping between the 2 so what you see might be by design.

You can use...

```
rpcclient -U {user} {ip of server}
```

and then this...

```
lookupnames {user}
```

will show the SID. `lookupsids` can be used to reverse the search.

But if the SID changes this is NOT a problem on the Ubuntu end. It will be a Windows problem. The id for a Linux user is found with `id $USER` and will never change unless you delete and recreate that user.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you say, it may be a problem on Windows side. I am also asking the developer about it.

Comment: @john no problem. do post an answer if you get any response fixing it. Ill remove mine

Answer (score 0):

The developer's response is that the only solution is to use Linux machine rather than WSL. Dual booting Windows & Linux eliminated this problem.
I appreciate your supports.